# how can I proof that a graph with 2n vertices is bipartite

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

If I have a graph without triangels 2n vertices and n^2 edges is it a bipartite graph? I couldn't find a counter example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A consequence of Turan's theorem:  If a graph, $G$, is traingle free, then $|E(G)| \le n^2/4$ where $n$ is the order of the graph.  Translating this to our specific case, we have that $E(G)=n^2 \le \frac{(2n)^2}{4}=n^2$.  Thus, our graph has the maximum number of edges to be triangle free, and so it is the Turan graph $T(2n,2)=K_{n,n}.$  Therefore, it is indeed bipartite.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: bipartiteness is equivalent to having no odd cycles.

Comment: So how do you prove that a triangle-free graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2$ edges has no odd cycles? (Other than by using Turan's theorem as in the other answer.)